# cmd ftp password error when logging in

Tags: batch-file, ftp, cmd

I'm trying to automate an ftp upload with a Batch script using the `ftp -s:commandsfile.ftp` command, at first everything seems OK: ftp server sends welcome message, username is automatically introduced, but when ftp asks for a password, nothing is introduced and all other commands that commandsfile.ftp sends return a "530 You aren't logged in" error:

```
Connected to ns12.dnchosting.com.
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 5 of 50 allowed.
220-Local time is now 16:02. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
User (ns12.dnchosting.com:(none)):
331 User [USERNAME]  OK. Password required

530 Login authentication failed
Login failed.
```

This is the commandsfile.ftp file:

```
open web12.dnchosting.com 
[USERNAME]
[PASSWORD] 
lcd 
cd afolder 
mkdir anotherfolder 
mput "*.*" 
disconnect 
bye
```

And this the batch script:

```
ftp -i -s:commandsfile.ftp
```

Why is CMD not introducing the password?

Comment: Have you verified the spelling of the password in the response file? Also have you verified the password works when you manually type it in an interactive session?

Comment: Yes, I did. I checked my file and manually created an FTP session. @dbenham

Answer (score 4):

Alright, problem solved... the ftp file had an extra space character at the end of each line, so that the password entered was the password plus an extra space because the ftp file is dynamically generated.