# Batch file ftp example using active connection

Tags: batch-file, ftp

Have done ftp connections using a Batch file in the past... but now I am experiencing problems as the current host requires an "Active" ftp connection. How would I script for this difference?

Comment: "experiencing problems" is very vague. What kind of problems? What error(s) does the server return when you try to connect? Where is your FTP script? The MS FTP.exe only works in Active mode as a client. You can use `QUOTE` or `LITERAL` to send `PASV` to the server but the client still only works in Active mode so there should be no issues connecting to an Active mode server.

Comment: Sorry... the explanation of the problem was vague... I was hoping for an example so I can just compare my script with the provided example to see what I was doing wrong. But the error I am getting is error 530 "Login Incorrect". Yes I have validated the credentials with a client ftp... and I have further verified the credentials several times.

Comment: Have you tried manually going through the connection with command line FTP?

Comment: That would be the ideal way to do it for sure... however in all honesty I am not a command line coder. It's been over 20 years since I have done any DOS commands... If I were familiar enough with it though this is what I would have done.

Comment: It's relatively simple. Just open a `CMD` prompt and type `FTP`. You'll go to an `FTP>` prompt. Type ? to get a list of commands. Start with `OPEN <server address>` then put in your password and try to do something on the server like `CD` to change directories or `LS` to list the contents. This is just a test to make sure you can actually connect and do stuff on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Apologize everyone... I actually found the problem I was having in a related post on Stack Overflow: [FTP Password Error Logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099308/cmd-ftp-password-error-when-logging-in/16401670#16401670) In I had assumed it was the Active Mode because I had a similar problem logging in with the FTP Client as well... until I switched it to "Active Mode". But it did take me some digging to find a FTP "Active Mode" Batch File example as it seems most examples were "Passive Mode" so here is an "Active Mode" example:

```
rem get files
echo open 555.555.55.555 
echo USERNAME
echo PASSWORD
echo cd FolderA
echo ascii
echo active

echo cd FolderB
echo mget *.*
echo mdelete *.*
echo close
echo bye
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic FTP connection script

```
 Ftp.txt

 USER MyUserId
 MyPassword
 Stuff to do on server


 FTP Command
 Ftp.exe -s Ftp.txt ftp.server.com
```